# got java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty when using cas

Tags: java, ssl, cas

we get the following exception in our application under tomcat which is using cas.

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
>   the trustAnchors parameter must be
>   non-empty

when I google for it I found some guess and solutions but no one can help me .

here is a part of our tomcat server.xml file:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="conf/.keystore" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

we point to our generated keystore.

Answer (score 21):

This bizarre error message usually means that your specified truststore was not found where you said it was.

Comment: Got your flag. Ran a check, nothing showing but will monitor.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped. My JVM was pointed to a different location with Java Options.

Comment: @EJP I never "messed" with your answer. I edited the answer that was changed by somebody else.

Comment: @Mr.Napik Post your own answer if you like, but don't mess with mine thanks.